# Mechanize submit login form from http to https

Tags: python, forms, post, https, mechanize

I have a web page containing a login form which loads via HTTP, but it submits the data via HTTPS.

I'm using python-mechanize to log into this site, but it seems that the data is submitted via HTTP.

My code is looks like this:

```
import mechanize
b = mechanize.Browser()
b.open('http://site.com')
form = b.forms().next()  # the login form is unnamed...
print form.action        # prints "https://login.us.site.com"
form['user'] = "guest"
form['pass'] = "guest"
b.form = form
b.submit()
```

When the form is submitted, the connection is made via HTTP and contains something like:

```
send: 'POST https://login.us.site.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 180\r\nHost: login.us.site.com\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n'...
```

Can anyone confirm this and eventually post a solution so that the form is submitted via HTTPS?

Later edit:

1) I'm using a HTTP proxy for http/https traffic (set in the environment - Linux machine)
2) I've watched the traffic with Wireshark and I can confirm that the traffic is sent via normal HTTP (I can see the content of the POST and mechanize doesn't send the same requests to the proxy as a webbrowser - the latter sends CONNECT login.us.site.com:443, while mechanize only POSTs https://login.us.site.com). However, I don't know what happens to the data as it leaves the proxy; perhaps it establishes a ssl connection to the target site?

Comment: your form seems to be submitted via HTTPS.

Comment: For the benefit of later readers:- It's bad practice to have a page served over http post to a https url. In default configuration IE (for example) will generate a warning in such cases....    If it is under your control you should serve the form from the same hostname and protocol as it will be submitted to. This also gives the user the reassuring padlock icon. (It's a defence against man-in-the-middle attacks - if the form is over HTTP, a MIM attacker can alter the form and can inject javascript to control what you submit to the HTTPS URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be a bug in mechanize

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=alpine.DEB.2.00.0910062211230.8646%40alice&forum_name=wwwsearch-general

Answer (score 2):

`mechanize` uses `urllib2` internally and the later had a bug: [HTTPS over (Squid) Proxy fails](http://bugs.python.org/issue1424152). The bug is fixed in Python 2.6.3, so updating Python should solve your problem.

Comment: While that bug indeed looks related, i doubt it's urllib2's fault, first because i run python 2.6.4 (up-to-date in my Ubuntu distribution) and second because I wrote a test program requesting https://www.paypal.com which indeed sends CONNECT through the proxy.
So it seems to be an issue related to mechanize..

Comment: Strange. I'm using urllib2 and able to urllib2.urlopen the page, but I receive same errors using urllib or mechanize.